# How to GET json data from API with a header

Tags: express, fullcontact

I'm trying to get JSON data from an API using NodeJS and Express, but it requires a header I'm not sure how to input the header into the get request.

The documentation says:

```
curl -H"X-FullContact-APIKey:$your_key" 
'https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=bart@fullcontact.com'
```

How do I do a add a get request with a header? I looked everywhere on Stackoverflow for days, and havent found anything. Everything is for PHP, nothing for NodeJS w/ Express. How can I do this with the Request Node NPM Manager Package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on how your request code looks like, but this should do it; right?

```js
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=bart@fullcontact.com',
  headers: {
    'X-FullContact-APIKey': '$your_key'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var result = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(result);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```